# Flask Radio buttons with choice for every user in table from database

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, ajaxform, flask-admin

I tried to create a html table from flask jinja2 template. I'm able to get all the data from database and make a table with rows and columns and radio buttons. But I'm unable to get choice for every user or row that is added to the table.

Unable to figure out how to do that. Should I make use of javascript,jquery or ajax to give radio button choice for every user or is there a way to solve this in flask template.

My code is as below:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/check_approve" method="post" id="admin_approve">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Privileges</th>
                <th>Approve</th>
                <th>Reject</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in data %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{item[0]}}<input type="hidden" name="empid" value={{item[0]}}></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="Privileges" form="admin_approve">
                        <option value="empty"> </option>
                        <option value="HR">HR</option>
                        <option value="Compensation Analyst">Compensation Analyst</option>
                        <option value="HR Manager">HR Manager</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class='radio'>
                    <label><input type='radio' id='choice1' name='approve' value="approve" checked></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class='radio'>
                    <label><input type='radio' id='choice2' name='reject' value="reject" checked></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button type="submit" form ="admin_approve" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Below is the attached screenshot. Appreciate your help.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0K5N.jpg)

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking or trying to accomplish here. I'm going to ask a few separate questions in additional comments; editing your question to address these may help you find an answer if you haven't already.

Comment: You say you're `unable to get choice for every user or row that is added to the table`, but the picture you've included does appear to show a set of choices. Can you explain (or give us an HTML/image mock-up of) what you're trying to accomplish, and/or how it differs from what you have now?

Comment: You've tagged the question for `flask`, `flask-wtforms`, `ajaxform`, and `flask-admin`, but the only code you've included is for the `jinja2` template. If all of these tags are accurate, you probably need to better explain (or provide more source that shows) how they fit in, here. *Depending on what you're aiming for* it might help to see the flask-admin view class, any custom `wtforms` classes, any javascript you're using to handle the form, or the `check_approve` view.